# how to pass in a column value in bigquery regexp_contains

Tags: sql, regex, search, google-bigquery, contains

The following query does not work for containsy but does for containsx and containsz
I want to be able to do search and replace with more flexibility with wildcards using word boundaries. I know I can do ' '||us||' ' as in
`REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),(' '||a.search||' ')) containsx .` 
I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax
`r'(?i)(\b.'||a.search||'.\b)')`
I want to be able to replace us but not when it is part of another word.

```
WITH t1 AS (
    select 'us' search, 'united states' replacex
) ,
t2 as (
    select 'usa us bus' old_string
    )
 
select REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),(a.search)) containsx, --working 
REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),r'(?i)(\b.'||a.search||'.\b)') containsy, --not working
REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),r'(?i)(\b.us.\b)') containsz, --working
old_string,
replace (b.old_string,a.search,a.replacex) new_string,
search,
replacex
from t1 a
cross join t2 b
where REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),(a.search));
```

| containsx | containsy | containsz | old_string | new_string | search | replacex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | usa us bus | united statesa united states bunited states | us | united states |

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| containsx | containsy | containsz | old_string | new_string | search | replacex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | usa us bus | usa united states bus | us | united states |

Comment: not clear what the question is! can  you please provide sample of input data and expected output along with logic to be applied

Comment: The expected output is the search and replace only replaces us with united states and

Comment: Please include sample data for us to reproduce.

Comment: The sample data is in the CTE t1 and t2

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t1 AS (
    select 'us' search, 'united states' replacex
) ,
t2 as (
    select 'usa us bus' old_string union all  
    select 'I must go to the us' union all  
    select 'there is no country here' union all
    select 'I blew a fuse in the us'
    )
select 
REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),CONCAT(r'(?i)(\b', a.search, r'\b)')) is_contains, 
old_string,
regexp_replace (b.old_string, CONCAT(r'(?i)(\b', a.search, r'\b)'),a.replacex) new_string,
replacex
from t1 a
cross join t2 b
where REGEXP_CONTAINS((b.old_string),CONCAT(r'(?i)(\b', a.search, r'\b)'))  ;
```

| is_contains | old_string | new_string | replacex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | usa us bus | usa united states bus | united states |
| TRUE | I must go to the us | I must go to the united states | united states |
| TRUE | I blew a fuse in the us | I blew a fuse in the united states | united states |